# Accept Xdialog username/password prompt using Enter key

Tags: gtk

I've inherited a script that uses `Xdialog` to request credentials from end-users on a terminal.

```bash
AUTH=`Xdialog --under-mouse --stdout --timeout 60 --password=2 --2inputsbox "Enter credentials" 40 100 "Username" "" "Password" ""`

USERNAME=`echo $AUTH | sed -e 's/\/.*//'`
PASSWORD=`echo $AUTH | sed -e 's/.*\///'`
```

The prompt shows two fields (with the second as a password field) and two buttons (<kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd>). The <kbd>OK</kbd> button has an outline indicating it should be the the default button.

The <kbd>Esc</kbd> key works as expected and cancels the prompt; however, the <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd> key does not accept/complete the prompt, instead the user must click <kbd>OK</kbd> (or tab to <kbd>OK</kbd> at which point <kbd>Enter</kbd> works).

Is accepting the prompt with <kbd>Enter</kbd> possible using `Xdialog`?